# How to make the print method in Kotlin have the same effect as Java

Tags: kotlin, println

I tried this code below in Kotlin. The `print` method cache the input data until I call the `println` method.

```
>>> print(1)
>>> print(2)
>>> System.out.print(3)
>>> System.out.print(4)
>>> println(5)
12345
```

I'd like to print the number as a sequence number by number like Java. How could I do that in Kotlin?

Update: Maybe someone misunderstands my question.

I want the `print` method print the input data immediately instead of waiting for `println` method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call `System.out.flush()` after `print`.

```
print(1)
System.out.flush()
```

Comment: Thank U for your suggestion. I can't understand why did Kotlin do that.

Comment: Buffering output until newline symbol is done for performance reasons, and not only in Kotlin. Java should be working the same way.

Comment: The flush is not working. I tested during debugging from Intellij IDE. Does not print.

Comment: @eigenfield same for me. This does not work.