# Why `print(String)` waiting until line-break before printing to console (Kotlin)?

Tags: java, kotlin, println

Lets have this code in Kotlin:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println("Start")
    var i = 1
    while (i <= 10) {
        Thread.sleep(500)
        print("... ")
        System.out.flush() // Suggest from another post, but it not working
        i++
    }
}
```

Why there is no output in console for 5 seconds and then everything is printed together in one go?

```
Start
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

I tried solution from [How to make the print method in Kotlin have the same effect as Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247440/how-to-make-the-print-method-in-kotlin-have-the-same-effect-as-java), but it does not work.

Comment: Please [undelete and edit your old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69865770/5133585) rather than post a new one.

Comment: @Sweeper But guide literally saying "If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one."

Comment: I simply can't reproduce the behaviour you are describing.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Is it [intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39798849/2970947)?

Comment: I am using Kotlin 1.5.31 compiled and run on Java 11, IDE Intellij IDEA

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes :D

Comment: Seems like ongoing Intellij IDEA or gradle bug...